# how to POST to google api (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to swap an authorization code I have received from the google API, following a user authorizing my app.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) say to make a POST request to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', which i am doing like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    data:{
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: google_redirect_uri,
        client_id: google_client_id,
        client_secret: google_client_secret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        alert('success')
    },
    error:function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    }
});
```

but I always get the error: 'cannot load 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?PARAMS', no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present

I'm confused about how I am supposed to make the request, to retrieve an access and refresh token, if I am obviously not on the same server?

I had a play on the oauth playgroun and that works fine, and makes the same request, details:

Request:

```
  POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
  Host: accounts.google.com
  Content-length: 265
  content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  user-agent: google-oauth-playground

  code=4%2FWYHrirFKijRaI25nMEU73_RdZ_fv__OJGb9B8HB6ofk.8ruOlJlXd6gYoiIBeO6P2m9MYnKclQI&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=&client_secret=************&grant_type=authorization_code
```

response:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.9gCiCc1tPxH2DLqvS2pUfmpJnyHJDXhEyI66V---wTrVobG-VKX_JRxdXodRwfR4ni7dv-I2Wy0neA", 
    "token_type": "Bearer", 
    "expires_in": 3600, 
    "refresh_token": "1/78DC9RfxmFtP7N7FEqpKk5Q-8jtURu67LVMWd5jCB40"
}
```

how can I make the request without it failing?